# How to 301 redirect in .htaccess with REGEX rewrite url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirection from the whole old subdirectory to new location in the same website with htaccess file. (I run wordpress website with redirection plugins but it take to much resources by adding more records.)

For example, if I want to do the Redirect 301 process from

**www.mydomain.com/olddirectory/page%**
to
**www.mydomain.com/newdirectory/specific-url/**

I have tried to search the example of using regular expression but I can't find them. Please suggest me about this matter.

Comment: try something like this in your htaccess file http://www.orderofbusiness.net/blog/redirect-old-domain-to-new-domain-via-htaccess/

Comment: Thanks for the link but there are nothings what I need. I need to know how to regular expression from www.mydomain.com/olddirectory/page(.*) to specific url in the same website.